# How could I get the first and last letters from a string?

Tags: vb.net

How can I get my program to take the first and last letters from an entered string?

Example: "I've been told I am a noob!"

Output: "IebntdIaman!"

I tried to use Split with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. since you have a couple of single character words I used a conditional in order to get your desired output. I also am using the [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that removes empty entries in order to prevent a zero length item, then I am taking the result and using the [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method to parse out your starting and ending chars.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim splitChar As String() = {" "}
    Dim example As String = " I've been told I am a noob!"
    Dim output As String = ""
    Dim result As String() = example.Split(splitChar, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    For Each item In result
        If item.Length > 1 Then
            output += item.Substring(0, 1) & item.Substring(item.Length - 1, 1)
        Else
            output += item.Substring(0, 1)
        End If
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(output)
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! However, I'm not 100% of what

`(0, 1) & item.Substring(item.Length - 1, 1)` 

means. Could you perhaps explain?

Comment: @ user2671434 I consider that a really silly question. you could take a loook into MSDN documentation or else use the intellisense feature to learn what each parameter does.

Comment: A string is actually an array of chars, what the first of those lines state is to start at the first letter of the string which is position 0 and to get just one character, which would be the first one. The second statement states that you want to start at the length of your string - 1 because your array is 0 based and to get one character. And the & operator just joins them together.

Comment: @ElektroStudios I'm sorry. I was just curious. I probably could have just looked at the documentation. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This works nicely:

```
Dim example As String = "I've been told I am a noob!"

Dim result = New String( _
    example _
        .Split(" "c) _
        .SelectMany(Function (w) _
            If(w.Count() = 1, _
                new Char() { w(0) }, _
                New Char() { w.First(), w.Last() })) _
        .ToArray())
'IebntdIaman!
```